# Regex get url value <a href="" ...</a>

Tags: php, regex

html output:

```
<a href="/projects/dorabotka-internet-magazina-na-openkart-3-1310872.html" target="_blank" title="Название">
                                                    <span title="Поднят" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
                            </span>
                                                Доработка интернет магазина на опенкарт 3                       </a>
```

My not working PHP code:

```
$terms = $doc_element->find('h2 a')->htmlOuter();
$terms = preg_filter('#<a href=\"(.)\".*$#is', "$1", $terms);
return $terms;
```

Problem with regex in 2nd line.

I need to get the value of the url, discarding everything else and put it before the url: https://example.com to end up with: https://example.com/projects/dorabotka-internet-magazina-na-openkart-3-1310872.html

Comment: Why not just get the ->href?

Comment: You're using some kind of HTML parser library. Why are you not using it features, but serializing the HTML into a string?

Comment: I use program that use library PHP Query (pq), if you can write a code that I can use in pq, will be great.

Comment: I just don't know the syntax and don't know the possible use cases, so I can't make the correct string myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
if (preg_match('#<a(?:\s+[^>]*?)?\s+href=["\']\K[^\'"]*#', $text, $match)) {
  echo 'https://example.com' . $match[0];
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rXJbzy/4).

*Details*:

- `<a` - a `<a` text
- `(?:\s+[^>]*?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitesapces
  - `[^>]*?` - zero or more chars other than `>` as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `href=["\']` - `href=` and then a `"` or a `'`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `[^\'"]*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `"`.

Comment: It's not working for me, I get just white screen in my program when use this code (CMS Drupal 7, module: https://github.com/xandeadx/parser ).

Comment: @user404405 I believe [it works as expected](https://3v4l.org/F3BYr).

Comment: I expected as output only url: http://example.com/projects/dorabotka-internet-magazina-na-openkart-3-1310872.html

Comment: @user404405 I updated the answer. See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/KnXZQ).

Comment: Thank you, everything works now, only I changed the variable name from $text to $terms.